# How to prevent direct access to files while allowing rewrite rules to access them

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What i want is to stop direct user requests to **online.php**, but i want the page to be still accessable for the rewrite rules, here is my rewrite rule

`RewriteRule ^/?@([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ online.php?username=$1`

And that is what i have tried but it didn't work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /online.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule .* page-not-found.php
```

The url of the original file which i want to hide is https://example.com/online.php?username=example
and the one that i only want to be accessed from is https://example.com/@example

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, please do add sample urls in your question which you want to block access for file.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure:

- To keep your htaccess and online.php file in same folder.
- Clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

##External redirect and blocking direct access for online.php file.
RewriteRule ^online\.php/?$ - [NC,F,L]

##External redirect and blocking direct access for online.php file.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/online\.php\?username=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

##Internal rewrite rules to rewrite to online.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ online.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you but i have a little problem when i try to access any of the user accounts /@exampleusername its returning me a 403 error

Comment: @0t9j, are you really usig `@` in url? I am not sure that is even allowed in url or not.

Comment: Yeah i use @ i mean tiktok uses the exact same url format